# return copy of an instance of a class, not a pointer in c++

Tags: c++

First; am I mistaken to assume that the `this` keyword is a **pointer** to the instance of the object I am working with, not a copy?

So if I had:

```
class someClass {
private:
    int _number;
public:
    someClass method(int number) {
        _number = number;
        return this;
    }
};
```

I would be returning a pointer to that instance?

If that is the case, how can I return a copy of that instance? I found a way but I think it's extremely awkward.

```
class someClass {
private:
    int _number;
public:
    someClass method(int number) {
        _number = number;
        someClass someClassObj;
        someClassObj._number = number;
        return someClassObj;
    }
};
```

Comment: `return *this`?

Comment: you return a copy of the class using `*this`. If you try and `return this` when it expect a value the code should not compile.

Answer (score 1):

You're right. `this` is a pointer to the current instance of the object (accessible in member functions).

If you want to return a copy of your class, there's a simple way that takes advantage of returning by value :

```
someClass returnCopy(){
    //Do whatever you want
    return *this
}
```

You simply dereference the `this` pointer, and return by value, which will make a copy of your current instance and return it.

Answer (score 1):

1. `this` in c++ is pointer only.Which has the address of `calling object`.

So in you code :

```
class someClass {
private:
    int _number;
public:
    someClass method(int number) {
        _number = number;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Note its `*this` so this obvious return the object of someclass.

2.And the second code snippet is completely valid and will work in your case :

```
class someClass {
private:
    int _number;
public:
    someClass method(int number) {
        _number = number;
        someClass someClassObj;
        someClassObj._number = number;
        return someClassObj;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this:

```
someClass method(int number) {
    _number = number;
    return *this;
}
```

But beware that if you have pointers in your class you often want to overload the copy constructor.

In your copy constructor you would usually wan't to create a copy of the object that the pointer points to and set the new someClass objects pointer to that instance.

Answer (score 0):

> First; am I mistaken to assume that the `this` keyword is a pointer to
>   the instance of the object I am working with, not a copy?

You are not mistaken at all. `this` is a pointer to the object that is executing the method. However, in your code there is a mistake:

```
someClass *method(int number) {
        _number = number;
        return this;
}
```

Since you are returning this, the correct way to write the method prototype would be declare it returns a pointer to the class, not an object to the class.

Or maybe you prefer to return the object itself. In that case, you must write `return *this` in order to get from the pointer to the actual object being pointed.

```
someClass method(int number) {
        _number = number;
        return *this;
}
```

But... ¡surprise! You're not returning the object pointed by this with this code, you'd actually be returning a copy to it. If you are really sure you'd like to return THE object pointed by `this`, then you should return a reference.

```
someClass &method(int number) {
        _number = number;
        return *this;
}
```

As you can see, what you were actually looking for is not so difficult: if you return any object without means of a reference, then you'll be actually copying it.

> how can I return a copy of that instance?

The way you did it is perfectly valid. But, a more common scenario would be to have a constructor accepting the number. Let's transform a little bit your code:

```
class Int {
private:
    int _number;
public:
    Int(int n): _number( n )
       {}
    int get() const
       { return _number; }
    Int copy() const
    {
        return someClass( get() );
    }
};
```

Here you a "more real" scenario in which you're actually copying the object itself. As you can see, your question involves a lot of issues (the very nature of C++ is about copying everything instead of using references (pointers) by default (as, for example, Java does)). in order to get deeper into C++, I'd recommend the help of good book, such as [C++ Primer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321714113).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -2):

Explicitly copy construct an instance:

```
class someClass {
private:
    int _number;
public:
    someClass(const someClass& that)
    : _number(that._number) { }

    someClass method(int number) {
        _number = number;
        someClass someClassObj;
        someClassObj._number = number;
        return someClass(this);
    }
};
```

Comment: Considering the negative vote score, I'm left to believe there is a flaw with my solution I do not immediately see?

Comment: Well, there is no point in doing this. The compiler synthesized copy constructor would do just fine. Just `return *this;`